# Rails not Showing HTML with Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a text area field. I'm trying to determine why it isn't showing line breaks `<br>` when I render views with the field.

My form:

```
<%= form_with model: [@channel, Message.new] do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>
  <%= form.submit 'Send' %>                        
<% end %>
```

In view:

```
<%= message.body.html_safe %>
```

In the view, even though I enter carriage returns after sentences, these don't reflect in the view. The text shows with no line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs for anything odd and make sure you have `body` added to the strong params.